# Update detached objects in EF that already exist in object state manager

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, repository

I'm hoping this will be an easy one but for the life of me, I cannot find the specific answer elsewhere on SO or any other site.

I have a basic repository/unit of work pattern with Entity Framework Code First. It all works smoothly except for certain cases of Update. THe problem is I have a set of Entity Framework model objects, all prefixed with "Db" which EF returns, but I then convert them to plain DataContract Model objects to pass to the Web layer to give separation of concerns. I have a basic conversion interface that just populates a WebModel object from the DataModel object, copying field by field verbatim.

So if you retrieve a DbUser object from EF with ID of 1, then convert to a User object, then convert that BACK to a DbUser object, you end up with a DbUser with ID of 1, but it is a DIFFERENT object to the one you started with, though they have the same primary key field, the actual CLR objects themselves are different.

The following works

```
User user;
using (var work = new UnitOfWork())
{
    var repository = new UserDataRepository(work);
    user = repository.Get(1);
    repository.save();
}

var modelUser = DataConverter.Convert(user);
modelUser.Name = "new name";
user = BusinessConverter.Convert(modelUser); 

using (var work = new UnitOfWork())
{
    var repository = new UserDataRepository(work);
    repository.Update(user);
    repository.save();
}
```

As they are using two different unit of works/contexts, so the second block has nothing in the ObjectStateManager to compare to and can just attach the detached object in the Update() methods

This, however does NOT work

```
using (var work = new UnitOfWork())
{
    var repository = new UserDataRepository(work);
    user = repository.Get(1);
    repository.save();

    var modelUser = DataConverter.Convert(user);
    modelUser.Name = "new name";
    user = BusinessConverter.Convert(modelUser)

    repository.Update(user);
    repository.save();
}
```

NOTE: I know logically this doesn't make much sense to convert and just convert back but go with it, I've simplified the example greatly to make it easier to put into paper, in my actual code there is a reason for doing it that way.

I get the usual error "an object with the same key already exists in the objectstatemanager...". I'm assuming because the Get() loads the object into EF and then the update sees that the object is detached, then tries to attach it and it already exists.

My Update method in my repository is as below

```
public override bool UpdateItem(DbUser item)
        {
            if (Work.Context.Entry(item).State == EntityState.Detached)
                Work.Context.Users.Attach(item);

            Work.Context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;

            return Work.Context.Entry(item).GetValidationResult().IsValid;
        }
```

Comment: why do you not use the working approach?

Comment: Bit complex to explain but basically one of my web service methods needs to get a "Post" from the database, update the view count to show that someone new has viewed this post, and return the post to the web layer. This involves a Get and an Update in the same UnitOfWork web method. Also its very inconvenient for Test frameworks as every time I get or update the repository, I need to destroy and recreate a new unit of work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might get a manged Entity, and again verbatim map the new `DbUser`'s properties to the managed Object:

```
public override bool UpdateItem(DbUser item)
{
  using (var work = new UnitOfWork())
  {
    var repository = new UserDataRepository(work);
    DbUser managedUser = repository.Get(item.PK);

    //foreach DbUser property map the item to managedUser
    managedUser.field1 = item.field1;
    [..]

    repository.Update(managedUser);
    repository.Save();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made this Extension method to the DbContext to ReAttach the Entity without problems try it out:

```
public static void ReAttach<T>(this DbContext context, T entity) where T : class
{
    var objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter) context).ObjectContext;
    var objSet = objContext.CreateObjectSet<T>();
    var entityKey = objContext.CreateEntityKey(objSet.EntitySet.Name, entity);

    Object foundEntity;
    var exists = objContext.TryGetObjectByKey(entityKey, out foundEntity);
    // Detach it here to prevent side-effects
    if (exists)
    {
        objContext.Detach(foundEntity);
    }
    context.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
}
```

Then just update your method :

```
public override bool UpdateItem(DbUser item)
{
    Work.Context.ReAttach(item);    
    Work.Context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;    
    return Work.Context.Entry(item).GetValidationResult().IsValid;
}
```

Comment: Tantalisingly close, though now I have a problem as I didn't mention my DbUser objet has a bunch of related entities held within it, eg UserAccount, UserSearchCriteria, IList<UserPhoto>, and I'm guessing something needs to also be done to detach these? Now with your extension method, when it hits the final line of re-attach I get the error "{"Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'DbUser_Account_Target' of the relationship 'MyStory.Data.EF.Contexts.DbUser_Account' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1."}"

Comment: @user1122909 please include such important information on the beforehand.

Comment: I gave this a vote because I found it useful, although, for those reading, I couldn't get it to work directly. The problem I experienced is that, if the `entity` was not modified from what was already in the DB, you get a `unexpected number of rows modified (0)...` exception (or something like that.) However, this code could be used to retrieve the `foundEntity` then do something like `context.Entry(foundEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you set your context to AsNoTracking() this will stop aspmvc tracking the changes to the entity in memory (which is what you want anyway on the web).

```
_dbContext.Products.AsNoTracking().Find(id);
```

I would recommend you read more about this at http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/advanced-entity-framework-scenarios-for-an-mvc-web-application

Yash